# What is the URL for a Google Cloud raw result root path (i.e. gs://... ) for FireBase Test Lab test

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-test-lab

I'm using the command `gcloud firebase test android run` to run my Android connected tests on Google FireBase Test Lab from the command line.  It's taking a long time to upload my `app-debug-androidTest.apk`.  It has output a URI for the bucket it will use, but how do I actually find that bucket on Google Cloud?

The bucket output by `gcloud firebase test android run` is:

```
INFO: Raw results root path is: [gs://test-lab-bcr7j9th055js-i215tdq3ht0hw/2019-04-19_15:36:10.931509_Etjx/]
```

Where do I go to see the contents of this bucket?

Answer (score 0):

To obtain a URL to buckets, I created a simpler application that had a smaller `debug-androidTest.apk` which uploaded right away.  It output the following URl once it got past the upload of the `debug-androidTest.apk`:

```
Raw results will be stored in your GCS bucket at [https://console.developers.google.com/storage/browser/test-lab-bcr7j9th055js-i215tdq3ht0hw/2019-04-19_15:41:26.364106_bmag/]
```

Since the `Raw results root path` is `gs://test-lab-bcr7j9th055js-i215tdq3ht0hw/2019-04-19_15:36:10.931509_Etjx/` I can guess that the corresponding URL is:

```
https://console.developers.google.com/storage/browser/test-lab-bcr7j9th055js-i215tdq3ht0hw/2019-04-19_15:36:10.931509_Etjx/
```

Visiting this URL in a web browser, I confirmed that the `debug-androidTest.apk` did not upload.  I waited a long time (half hour?) and finally it got past the upload step and output the URL, which I had guessed correctly.

Comment: Note: the gs:// syntax is compatible for use with the `gsutil` command-line tool, which lets you inspect the contents of cloud buckets and copy files to/from buckets. You correctly inferred the right URL to view the results from the web console.


                  Also, you can exercise control over where your test results are stored by using the `--results-bucket=RESULTS_BUCKET_NAME` flag and/or the `--results-dir=UNIQUE_RESULTS_DIR` flag.  More details about the ramifications of using these flags can be found at https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/firebase/test/android/run

Comment: Also note that `test-lab-bcr7j9th055js-i215tdq3ht0hw` is your assigned free-usage bucket. It should remain your default test results bucket for the life of your Firebase project, unless you delete it.